# Jquery Ajax form with foreach php variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a group of checkboxes with the same name and id, but have different variables that I want submitted with my jquery ajax form.  The checkbox looks like this:

```
<input class="checkbox" name="<? echo"description_list[$i]";?>" id="<? echo"description_list[$i]";?>" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $row['description'];?>" />&nbsp;<? echo $row['description'];?><br />
```

and the call to jquery looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.formSub').live('click',function() {                     

var store = $("#store").val();
var type = $("#type").val();
var business_name=$("#business_name").val();
var first_name=$("#first_name").val();
var last_name=$("#last_name").val();
var phone = $("#phone").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var make = $("#make").val();
var model = $("#model").val();
var esn = $("#esn").val();
var lock = $("#lock").val();
var description = $("#description").val();

var <? echo"description_list[$i]";?> = $("#<? echo"description_list[$i]";?>").val();

var dataString = 'store='+store+'&type='+type+'&business_name='+business_name+'&phone='+phone+'&email='+email+'&make='+make+'&model='+model+'&esn='+esn+'&lock='+lock+'&description='+description+'&<? echo"description_list[$i]";?>='+<? echo"description_list[$i]";?>;

if(esn=='')
{
$('.error').show().fadeOut(3000);
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "somefile.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(response){

$('#customerInfo').slideUp(500);
$('#repairResult').delay(500).slideDown(500);

}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Not sure how to get it to do the loop on the foreach description[$i]... if someone could help would greatly appreciate.

Thanks Andron... this is what I ended up with... works perfect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#input_form").submit(function(){
             var querystring = $(this).serialize();     
         $.post("submit.php", $(this).serialize());     
    $('#customerInfo').slideUp(500);
            $('#repairResult').delay(500).slideDown(500);
             return false;
             });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *"I have a group of checkboxes with the same name and id"*. No need to read further. It's invalid. Only one element in a page can have a given id.

Comment: it works fine if i submit without jquery and ajax... just having the action set to a file.  Is there not a way to do this with jquery and ajax?

Comment: i guess they all have different id's because the [$i] gives each a uniqueness.

Comment: So you asked if possible to submit form data in other way - yes, sure please check [JQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Also I think you need to be double sure that ids are unique.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Jquery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to collect fields + data for submission.

Comment: Thanks Andron... I think serialize is going to work